# Google Sheets - Multiply/Concatenate String Arrays

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Suppose I have three columns importing data from elsewhere, like so:

| Name | Company | Division |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Meta | Ops |
| Betty | Nvidia | Sales |
| Carl | OpenAI | Development |

The number of values in each column may change from time to time as the report is run.
I want to create a column that combines the data in such a way:

| Combined |
| --- |
| Adam - Meta - Ops |
| Adam - Meta - Sales |
| Adam - Meta - Development |
| Adam - Nvidia - Ops |
| Adam - Nvidia - Sales |
| Adam - Nvidia - Development |
| Adam - OpenAI - Ops |
| Adam - OpenAI - Sales |
| Adam - OpenAI - Development |
| Betty - Meta - Ops |
| Betta - Meta - Sales |
| Betty - Meta - Development |
| Betty - Nvidia - Ops |

.... etc.

I've tried various setups with arrayformula concat() with no luck. I was hoping this could be solved with just formulas and not needing any scripting.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].